# Magento2 - How to install Magento Sample data using command line

Tags: magento2, installation

How to install Magento Sample data using command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following CLI command to install Magento 2 sample data.

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Add Access Key. You can get from Market Place

**Note:** If you get a memory error message, run the following command.

```
php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

After successfully installing Magento2 sample data, run the following commands one by one.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks